# simple encode using c by substract char

Tags: c, encode

i use c language for my program(my practice). this code is work if i use 1 string in every variable. But, when i use array of string (2 dimension variable), str2[x] (the second string) isn't encoded, only str1[x] & str3[x] .

here my code (i get this code by browsing in here):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

char *encode(char *str){
  int i=0;
  while(str[i]!='\0'){
    str[i]=str[i]-18;
    i++;
  }
  return str;
}

int main(){
  int i,n;
  char str1[50][50],str2[50][50],str3[50][50];

  printf("How many data: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("String 1: ");
      scanf("%s",str1[i]);
    printf("String 2: ");
      scanf("%s",str2[i]);
    printf("String 3: ");
      scanf("%s",str3[i]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("index-%d: %s - %s - %s\n",i,encode(str1[i]),encode(str2[i]),encode(str3[i]));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

for example, i input 2 data.

first input: `"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"`
Second input: `"Test4", "Test5", "Test6"`

output for index-0 for ex: `index-0: BSab[ -  - BSab!` (the second process is skiped) and no output for index-1 because the process is stop, i don't know why.

Comment: Works here: https://ideone.com/zgcZbC. How are you setting the strings?

Comment: it's weird, when i try this code before i share my problem, i always fail. but, now it's work. ok thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `fflush(stdin);` which is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/3425536).